# How to find out the ret address

Tags: assembly, buffer, x86-64, buffer-overflow

```
void function(int a, int b, int c)
{    char buffer[1];
     int *ret;
     ret = buffer + 20;
     (*ret) += 7;
}
void main()
{    int x;
    x = 0;
    function(1, 2, 3);
    x = 1;
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

In this program, what i would like to do is to rewrite the return register address so that the result of the program is to print "0" not "1" as the value of x in the main.

But I failed to find out the return address - the offset of the buffer, and the offset of the return address.

Here is part of the assembly language:

```
function:
.LFB0:
.cfi_startproc
pushq   %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.cfi_offset 6, -16
movq    %rsp, %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 6
movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
movl    %esi, -24(%rbp)
movl    %edx, -28(%rbp)
leaq    -9(%rbp), %rax
addq    $20, %rax
movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
movl    (%rax), %eax
leal    7(%rax), %edx
movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
movl    %edx, (%rax)
popq    %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
ret
.cfi_endproc
```

and,

```
main:
.LFB1:
.cfi_startproc
pushq   %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.cfi_offset 6, -16
movq    %rsp, %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 6
subq    $16, %rsp
movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
movl    $3, %edx
movl    $2, %esi
movl    $1, %edi
call    function
movl    $1, -4(%rbp)
movl    $.LC0, %eax
movl    -4(%rbp), %edx
movl    %edx, %esi
movq    %rax, %rdi
movl    $0, %eax
call    printf
leave
.cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
ret
.cfi_endproc
```

After compiling, I use the gdb to find out the return address

```
   0x000000000040054e <+0>: push   %rbp
0x000000000040054f <+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x0000000000400552 <+4>:    sub    $0x10,%rsp
0x0000000000400556 <+8>:    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
0x000000000040055d <+15>:   mov    $0x3,%edx
0x0000000000400562 <+20>:   mov    $0x2,%esi
0x0000000000400567 <+25>:   mov    $0x1,%edi
0x000000000040056c <+30>:   callq  0x400524 <function>
0x0000000000400571 <+35>:   movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
0x0000000000400578 <+42>:   mov    $0x400694,%eax
0x000000000040057d <+47>:   mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
0x0000000000400580 <+50>:   mov    %edx,%esi
0x0000000000400582 <+52>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
0x0000000000400585 <+55>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x000000000040058a <+60>:   callq  0x400418 <printf@plt>
0x000000000040058f <+65>:   leaveq 
0x0000000000400590 <+66>:   retq
```

That is why I choose "20" and "7". But it doesn't work, it says "segment error". I've tried many numbers, and sometimes it comes "bus error". I don't know why and how could I find it. I'm running it on a 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the code with my comments:

```
function:
pushq   %rbp ; save rbp on the stack
movq    %rsp, %rbp ; rbp = address of previous value of rbp on the stack
movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
movl    %esi, -24(%rbp)
movl    %edx, -28(%rbp)
leaq    -9(%rbp), %rax ; rax = address of buffer = rbp - 9
addq    $20, %rax ; rax = buffer + 20 = rbp - 9 + 20 = rbp + 11
movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
movl    (%rax), %eax ; read 4 bytes from address rbp + 11, WHY 4? 8-byte pointers!
leal    7(%rax), %edx ; add 7 to those
movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
movl    %edx, (%rax) ; store the sub back
popq    %rbp ; restore rbp from the stack
ret ; return
```

Note that the last two instructions (pop and ret) pop two items from the stack, the previous/saved value of rbp and the return address.

This means that the return address is right above the saved rbp value on the stack, or at rbp + 8.

But you are modifying the memory at rbp + 11.

Further, you're modifying only 4 bytes, whereas all pointers are 64-bit (8-byte).

So, you need to change

```
int *ret;
```

to

```
unsigned long long *ret;
```

and then correct the constant, so you modify 8 bytes at address rbp + 8 and not at rbp + 11 or rbp + something else.

Rocket science? Nope. Just read the code, step through it, see what happens and think. You've got the debugger!

Comment: Thanks so much! I've some more questions about it. what are the movl %rax, -8(%rbp) and the movl -8(%rbp), %rax do?

Comment: Move 4 bytes between rax and memory at rbp-8. Read assembly tutorials and the CPU manual.'

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio, consider calling the compiler intrinsic

```
void* _ReturnAddress(void);
#pragma intrinsic(_ReturnAddress);

function main()
{
    void* ret = _ReturnAddress();
    printf("%p", ret);
}
```